How can I solve: InvalidCharacterError: The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range
In VS Code I want to 'quarto render' a website but I receive the following error:
ERROR: InvalidCharacterError: The string to be encoded contains characters outside of the Latin1 range.

Stack trace:
    at btoa (ext:deno_web/05_base64.js:52:13)
    at Object.utilities.metadataAttrs (file:///Applications/quarto/bin/quarto.js:97808:34)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (file:///Applications/quarto/bin/quarto.js:3925:16), <anonymous>:50:29)
    at renderEjs (file:///Applications/quarto/bin/quarto.js:90388:18)
    at include (file:///Applications/quarto/bin/quarto.js:90399:28)
    at partial (eval at <anonymous> (file:///Applications/quarto/bin/quarto.js:3925:16), <anonymous>:9:40)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (file:///Applications/quarto/bin/quarto.js:3925:16), <anonymous>:19:2)
    at renderEjs (file:///Applications/quarto/bin/quarto.js:90388:18)
    at templateMarkdownHandler (file:///Applications/quarto/bin/quarto.js:97630:28)
    at markdownHandler (file:///Applications/quarto/bin/quarto.js:98572:24)

The presentation.qmd file already has the UTF-8 encoding. Thanks for any help.
Sebastian

Could you please share some reproducible code?
